# jqGrid 4.5.2 with bit data and null dates returned

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, nan, formatter

Using jQuery 1.9.1 & jqGrid 4.5.2 to create a grid on a web page.

The data that's being returned from a SQL query has 2 date fields in it, along with a field that is declared as a Bit in SQL.  When I run the stored procedure in Query Analyzer, I get a valid date in the first date field, it shows a 1 in the bit field, and `NULL` in the second date field on the row.

In the `colModel` of jqGrid, I have the 2 fields set up as follows:

```
{name:"AckSwitch",
index:"AckSwitch",
width:200,
align:"left",
sorttype:"text",
xmlmap:"Rowset>Row>AckSwitch"
},
{name:"AckTime",
index:"AckTime",
width:60,
align:"center",
sorttype:"date",
formatter:"date",
formatoptions: {"newformat":"m/d/Y H:i" },
datefmt: "m/d/Y H:i",
xmlmap:"Rowset>Row>AckTime"
}
```

When the `NULL` time is returned, the column in the jqGrid displays like:

```
NaN/NaN/NaN
NaN:NaN
```

I had found an example where a null date as passed in and the above formatter returned as a blank in it, but mine only returns the NaN above.

How do you  need to set up a formatter to allow null values in a date field in jqGrid?  And secondly, on the Bit field, can you create a custom formatter to show True/False instead of 1 or NULL (which is what it would be if not set).  Both fields would need to be sortable.

Would appreciate any suggestions or guidance.

Thanks!

Comment: What does your XML data contain for the date value? I've verified that your format options work (display blank) with a value of NULL passed to the grid for that column, so I'm guessing that the problem is occurring in the SQL -> XML step...

Comment: @DanielSimpkins - what is passed back in the XML in that node is:  `<AckTime>TimeUnavailable</AckTime>`.

Comment: Well there's your problem. JqGrid is attempting to convert the string "TimeUnavailable" to a date, which it obviously can't do. If the date is null, then you need the value "Null" in your XML node.

Comment: @DanielSimpkins - thanks for your help.  I was able to re-do the SQL and cast it as a varchar, formatting it in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm format so that it would accept a blank in it instead of a null, and also changed the `sorttype` on the grid to be text so it is sorting Left to Right.

Comment: Glad to help. I've had my share of struggles with JqGrid. It's quite fickle.